# Tensorflow Linear Regression NaN output

Tags: python, tensorflow, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to write code for a Machine Learning algorithm to learn both Machine Learning concepts and Tensorflow. The algorithm I am trying to write up is:

(Not enough reputation to embed an image) https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqxEB.png

"Which is equivalent to a piece wise linear regression model."

From (Equation 7):

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.3315.pdf

I've loaded in the vectors I want to do this on. And initialised my placeholders and variables:

```
size = len(originalVecs)
_x1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[size, 300], name="x1-input")
_x2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float64, shape=[size, 300], name="x2-input")

_w = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([300,300], -1, 1, dtype = tf.float64), name="weight1")
```

My prediction, cost, and training step I've set as I have set as:

```
prediction = tf.matmul(_x1,_w)
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.norm(prediction - _x2)))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
```

After I initialize I train with the following:

```
for i in range(10000):
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={_x1: timedVecs, _x2 : originalVecs})
    if i % 1001 == 0:
        print('Epoch ', i)
        print('Prediction ', sess.run(prediction, feed_dict={_x1: timedVecs, _x2 : originalVecs}).shape)
```

When I run my code it is wildly unstable and just grows within about 20 iterations to just print NaNs. I think I'm doing a couple of things wrong but I do not know how to correct.

The shape of the prediction is [20,300] when I would expect it to be [1,300]. I want it to predict based off a single x1 and x2, rather than all at once then try to learn from the sum of the error for all data points (what I assume piecewise is). I'm not sure how to go about this however as I think currently I'm minimising based on the 20,300 matrix rather than the sum of 20 1,300 matrices.

I assume matmul is correct as multiply is element wise?

I am entering my input data as a list of np arrays. Each np array being a data point with 300 dimensions.

Thank you.

Comment: I haven't looked too much into it but `tf.norm` as you are using it flattens the tensor and computes the norm over the resulting vector. Since you also have `tf.reduce_sum` It makes me think you actually want to compute the norm over `prediction` rows. You can use the `axis` argument for that.

Comment: You're right, I did miss that. Norm should be calculating the vector norms and return an array with 20 entries. I've corrected that but the error is still propagating. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally I'd avoid square roots in losses. The issue is that the derivative of `x**0.5` is `0.5 * x**-0.5`, which means dividing by `x`. If `x` is ever zero, this will produce NaNs. In this case the square root comes from `tf.norm` and is immediately followed by `tf.square`, but the operations aren't fused together and don't cancel.

Simplifying your loss expression to `tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(prediction - _x2))` should make things more stable.